# Dynamic value based on input value in java

Tags: java, spring-boot, java-8, casting, typecasting-operator

I am having one class as below.

```
public class ResponseData {
    private Long entityId;
    private String type;
    private List<String> value;
}
```

Problem Statement :

I am sending List of ResponseData to caller in JSON format.

Possible values of type variable is "String", "Integer", "Date", "Time" and "Reference"

My requirement is if value of type is "Integer" or "Reference" then type of value field should be List of Integer and for rest all values of type field, type of value field should be List of String.

Comment: What JSON parser are you using - Jackson?

Comment: Yes Jackson parser

Answer (score 1):

You can use a parameterized class with a custom deserializer. Here is a working code.

- `ResponseData<T>`: Parameterized class with the list's element type as the parameter
- `DS`: A custom Jackson deserializer that understands how to map into `ResponseData<T>`

(I have used Lombok annotations for ease.)

Notice that `ResponseData<T>` has been annotated with `@JsonDeserialize` to indicate that deserialization into an object of the class should use this deserializer. Rest should be self explanatory.

```java
public class DynamicTypes{
    @NoArgsConstructor @AllArgsConstructor( staticName = "of" )
    @Getter @Setter @ToString
    @JsonDeserialize(using = DS.class)
    public static class ResponseData<T>{
        private Long entityId;
        private String type;
        private List<T> value;
    }
    
    public static void main( String[] args ){
        try{
            ObjectMapper m = new ObjectMapper();
            
            List<String> inputJSONs = Arrays.asList( 
                    "{\"entityId\":1,\"type\":\"String\",\"value\":[\"ONE\",\"TWO\"]}",
                    "{\"entityId\":2,\"type\":\"Integer\",\"value\":[1,2]}" );
            
            for( String json : inputJSONs ) {
                ResponseData<?> rd = m.readValue( json, ResponseData.class );
                System.out.println( rd );
            }
        }
        catch( JsonProcessingException e ){
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    
    private static class DS extends StdDeserializer<ResponseData<?>>{
        protected DS(){
            super( ResponseData.class );
        }
        
        @Override
        public ResponseData<?> deserialize(JsonParser jp, DeserializationContext ctxt) 
          throws IOException, JsonProcessingException {
            JsonNode node = jp.getCodec().readTree( jp );
            String type = node.get( "type" ).asText();

            String valueText = node.get( "value" ).toString();
            ObjectMapper om = new ObjectMapper();
            ResponseData<?> rd = new ResponseData<>();
            switch( type ) {
                case "Integer":
                case "Reference":
                    ResponseData<Integer> rdInt = new ResponseData<>();
                    List<Integer> valueInt = om.readValue( valueText, new TypeReference<List<Integer>>(){} );
                    rdInt.setValue( valueInt );
                    rd = rdInt;
                    break;
                default:
                    ResponseData<String> rdStr = new ResponseData<>();
                    List<String> valueStr = om.readValue( valueText, new TypeReference<List<String>>(){} );
                    rdStr.setValue( valueStr );
                    rd = rdStr;
            }
            
            rd.setEntityId( node.get( "entityId" ).asLong() );
            rd.setType( type );
            
            return rd;
        }
    }
}
```